# Huge difference beetween 2 versions of ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, kernel, updates

I have installed ubuntu 12.04 LTS on my laptop(now through updates i have 12.04.2) and I installed 12.04.2 LTS on my girlfriend's laptop and they have different kernels.

While mine has kernel version 3.2, my girlfriend's has 3.5.

I see [here](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/) the 3.5 doesn't have a version for precise.Is it a good/bad thing?

Should I upgrade to kernel 3.5 myself?

Comment: That is not a huge difference ;) My opinion: if your system works and does what you want it to do why would you? You choose LTS so the general idea is to stick with your stable(!) system and not 'bleeding' edge. Your choice :-)

Comment: also see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/248914/what-is-hwe-hardware-enablement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i encountered the same difference, when i installed the newest version for a friend.
it turns out, that there is a package, that you can install as an update by your own, that is not installed automatically for yout with any sort of update-procedure.

> sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic-lts-quantal linux-headers-generic-lts-quantal

should do the trick. This also keeps the newly installed kernel 3.5 up to date!

If you encounter problems with samba or proprietary drivers, simply reinstall them...