# Ubuntu Server how to upgrade to 12.04.3 with kernel 3.8 from 12.04.2 with kernel 3.5?

Tags: 12.04, kernel, hardware-enablement-stack

Ubuntu Server how to upgrade to 12.04.3 with kernel 3.8 from 12.04.2 with kernel 3.5?
It seemed I have seen some doc saying upgrade to kernel 3.8, but forget where the doc is.
So new a topic.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/248914/what-is-hardware-enablement-hwe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The document you were looking for was probably the [LTS Enablement Stacks](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack) article.

You don't necessarily have to wait for a LTS-point-release update to install the newer kernel from the latest non-LTS-release. The kernel is published in the LTS repository usually a few weeks or months (**To the experts:** Is there a specific [release schedule](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ReleaseSchedule) I don't know about?) after the non-LTS is finally released and available via meta packages following this scheme:

```
linux-generic-lts-quantal
linux-generic-lts-raring
linux-generic-lts-saucy
...
```

or install the `linux-hwe-generic` package to get the latest HWE kernel.

Comment: Just to note for other visitors with a GUI installed - If you install a newer Linux kernel, you should also upgrade the Xorg stack. Otherwise you'll end up in an unsupported state. *"Intermixing a 13.04 enablement kernel with the 12.04 X.org stack or a 13.04 enablement X.org stack with a 12.04 kernel will not be officially tested nor supported."* https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

Comment: It seems not easy.

Comment: @Honghe.Wu What exactly do you mean? It's as easy as installing package! This really doesn't get any easier, I'm afraid.

Comment: after `sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-raring` and reboot, it stop on `checking disk for errors`, so what's wrong? Ubuntu Server are on QEMU emulator on x86 arch.

Comment: You know that checking for filesystem errors is performed when the mount count reaches the maximum mount count? Are you sure that the check was caused by something else than this? (You can display the attributes for EXT[234] via `tune2fs -l /dev/$devicename`)

Answer (score 1):

> it stop on checking disk for errors

The VM may not really be stopped, try changing video adapter to VGA: http://blog.peacon.co.uk/ubuntu-13-04-kvm-vm-boot-hang/

Comment: Thx. Ubuntu is on VMware workstation