# Linux Kernel 3.10.17 upgrade in 12.04 64bit?

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, kernel

I found an article on G+ about needing to upgrade the kernel to 3.10.17 for Ubuntu versions from 12.04 through 13.10.

http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/10/linux-kernel-3-10-17-upgrade-ubuntu-linux-mint/

is this suggested? Has anyone found any problems with it? and why an urgent upgrade?

my current one is 3.8.0-32-generic

Comment: The article doesn't say you need to upgrade, unless already using kernel 3.10. Furthermore, as 3.10 is not used by default in Ubuntu, upgrading is neither suggested nor recommended.

Comment: I don't see any particular reason why you should upgrade in the changelog. If it's working fine why you must upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

You can install any kernel you want. There is no problem on using one or multiple Kernels at a time. Updating to a new Kernel keeps you up-to-date with Security Patches, Stability Improvements, Updated Drivers, and New Kernel Functions.

The [link](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/10/linux-kernel-3-10-17-upgrade-ubuntu-linux-mint/) you mentioned is talking about to install a latest kernel. But you can see that **Kernel 3.10.17** is not the latest one. You can find that [**Kernel 3.11.6**](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/) is the latest stable release now.

As you can find that in every 2 weeks [a new kernel](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/) is released. So it doesn't mean that you've to update kernels after every two weeks. :) What I suggest you to stick with the kernels which is running without any problem.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with Kernel 3.11 without any problem. But sometime you should consider the Kernel Mapping to your Ubuntu Version. For example following link lists out the mapping of different kernel to different version of OS (go to precise section):

[Ubuntu to Mainline kernel version mapping](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/info/kernel-version-map.html)

The link you provided is a nice tutorial, you can also also get a complete information of Kernel installing/removing from following link.

[Kernel Mainline Builds](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds)

Following link illustrates how Ubuntu 12.04 LTS works actually. It illustates in very nice way, you would also like:

[Ubuntu LTS Enablement Stack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack?action=fullsearch&context=180&value=How+to+upgrade+to+ubuntu+12.04.3&titlesearch=Titles)

Comment: Mainline Kernel != "Ubuntu Kernel". Please don't adivse users to install every possible kernel. Kernel updates and backports for Ubuntu are installed automatically. There is no need to install other kernel packages when everything works.

Comment: @LiveWireBT: Thanks for reading my post. I'll suggest you to read once again. This time completely..

Comment: I read it completely and I also read it like a lazy user would do, focusing on bold text and links. Which would lead me to http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/ the worst of all pages for users who want a simple answer. Twice. I'm not saying my answer is better. But the first thing that should be clearly answered here is: No you shouldn't do that. Then explain why, then show alternatives. I recommend you restructure your post, because you can't rely on users reading carefully when your most prominent link is the most dangerous one.

Comment: @LiveWireBT: You're lazy it doesn't mean OP and others are lazy. In first comment you are advising me not to advise others to install any kernels(without reading my post.) In 2nd comment your scenario completely changed and now talking about mainline kernels. If you read once again then you'll notice that I'm using that link to show the latest version of Kernel Released, and who told you that the link is worst link. It would be worst for you but it is the only link mentioned [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds). I don't know what is your problem.

Comment: I'm speechless. You should read your own post and try to understand what you wrote, not from your point of view. (And doublecheck on the link duplicate.) Then you should read good well structured answers on other questions. Who said it's a bad link? Find out! The answer is right in front of you. (In your own links!)

Answer (score 0):

Oh, well. The more I read about ubuntuhandbook.org here from users, the more I wish it would die instantly, because such low quality copypasta without explanation harms users.

See the section on Launchpad PPAs below for more details. (The package that the guide tells you to download is from Kernel Team PPA.)

### Automatic kernel updates

You don't need to install additional kernel packages or external sources in Ubuntu. Everything is done for you automatically through the Software Updater. To be more specific, there exists a meta package that always points to the latest kernel that is available in this Ubuntu release.

Running saucy this is the current state:

```
$ aptitude show linux-image
Package: linux-image              
State: not installed
Version: 3.11.0.12.13
Priority: optional
Section: kernel
Maintainer: Ubuntu Kernel Team <kernel-team@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: amd64
Uncompressed Size: 33,8 k
Depends: linux-image-generic
Conflicts: linux-image
Provided by: linux-image-3.11.0-11-lowlatency, linux-image-3.11.0-12-generic, linux-image-3.11.0-8-generic
Description: Generic Linux kernel image.
 This package will always depend on the latest generic Linux kernel image and headers.
```

If you run another Ubuntu release, that is not End of Life (EOL), don't fear, you are still covered and receive security patches and bugfixes for your kernel automatically.

### Other kernels

- **Ubuntu HWE-Kernels**

  See this question: [What is hardware enablement (HWE)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/248914/what-is-hardware-enablement-hwe)
- **Launchpad PPAs**

  Citation from [Kernel Team PPA](https://launchpad.net/~canonical-kernel-team/+archive/ppa):

  > PPA description
  >
  > This ppa is used for building pre-release and test kernels.
  >
  > It IS NOT RECOMMENDED that you subscribe to this PPA.

  For other PPAs see this question: [Are PPA's safe to add to my system and what are some "red flags" to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out-fo)
- **Kernel.org Kernels**

  See the page about [Active kernel releases on kernel.org.](https://www.kernel.org/category/releases.html) If you are a kernel developer, then you already use these kernels and don't care much about kernel updates from your distribution. If you are not, using these will not automatically make you one.