# Can I upgrade Ubuntu 12.04 (dual boot) to 13.04 from a DVD

Tags: 12.04, 13.04, dual-boot, upgrade, nic

I use Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on a dual boot system. I upgraded my PC's motherboard to Gigabyte GA-H77M-D3H motherboard. 12.04 no longer sees the network interface ! 
I now want to upgrade to 13.04.
Is there a 13.04 download I can put onto a DVD and then upgrade 12.04 after I have booted up 12.04 ?

Comment: You might want to consider upgrading to 13.10 instead as [support for 13.04 ends in January](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases). Or install the [Hardware Enablement Stack](http://askubuntu.com/questions/248914/what-is-hardware-enablement-hwe).

Answer (score 0):

Boot with the live CD/DVD of the new version. ***If*** this can see the network card it should connect to the internet and give you the upgrade option when you select install.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can upgrade to 13.04 using a DVD instalation.
Just put the DVD in as you would normally install ubuntu, and when this screen apears:
[image]
Just make sure you chose to upgrade.