# USB Bluetooth Adapter Not Working in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, kernel, bluetooth

I have a USB Bluetooth adapter (0a12:0001) that has some problems under Trusty. It works about 50% of the time, and if I unplug it and reconnect it, then it works again.

I know this is a known issue. I've read the bug reports. I also know that this is fixed in 14.10 Utopic Unicorn (fixed in kernel 3.14+, Trusty has 3.13), but I can't update to Utopic because Utopic is not an LTS release, and I need an LTS release for what I'm using my computer for.

I don't want to compile and install a newer version of the kernel, as I have failed before and had to reinstall. What I am asking is, how can I fix this without having to compile and install a newer version of Linux or updating to Utopic? (I'm okay with updating my kernel with `apt` or something, as long as there is little to no chance of me messing up).

Comment: The Utopic Kernel will be available as an [HWE-Kernel](http://askubuntu.com/q/248914/40581) for 14.04 LTS, a few weeks after Utopic has been released.

Comment: For those reading this, the HWE kernel is now available and can be installed with the command 'sudo apt-get install linux-hwe-generic-trusty'. This will also install the headers.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 14.04 (current patches up to 1/15/2015)
Lenovo ThinkPad W530.

I found the Cirago BTA8000 at Fry's Electronics for $19.99.
It was literally "plug and play".

I tried several different brands and kept returning them because they couldn't be made to work.

When I plugged in the BTA8000, I thought it was another failure - no dings, no horns, nothing to indicate a success. 
But, the BTA8000 was blinking every 1 or 2 seconds. 
Then I noticed the bluetooth icon on the upper right screen boarder.

I used one of the W530's USB 2.0 ports and it come right up.
No drivers to load, no services to start, no fiddling and no issues.

I have now paired my Apple keyboard and the Logitech bluetooth mouse. Each went painlessly and exactly as I would hope.

Cirago Bluetooth 4.0 Mini USB Adapter
EDR / Low Energy
Backwards compatible 1.1/1.2/2.0/3.0
www.cirago.com.

Comment: I had to `sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-trusty` and reboot in order for this to work