# Why is the server version of 14.04.1 (supported until 2019) not available for download?

Tags: 14.04, server, downloads, lts

On the ubuntu.com download page for Server, I can only download 14.04.2. But this version is not LTS (EOL is august 2016).

14.04.1 is supported until 2019 [according to the LTS Enablement Stack page of the Ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack#Kernel.2BAC8-Support.A14.04.x_Ubuntu_Kernel_Support), but is not available in the "alternative downloads". The folder 14.04 is a link to 14.04.2.

Is it a mistake?

By the way, the download page seems misleading when it says 14.04.2 is a LTS version supported until 2019.

Comment: Point releases are images with (sic) up to date security updates, LTS enablement stack refers only to the availability of new kernel and graphic drivers for LTS release.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge 14.04 is an LTS version regardless of the point designation (.0, .1, .2)

Comment: Did you see the link at the end about LTSEnablementStack? I understand that dot release contains up to date drivers but it seems that not all dot release are LTS. What did I miss?

Comment: @sudodus thank you so much for providing an answer here :)

Comment: @Zanna, You are welcome. I'm glad that I can help and I appreciate *your* work to improve old questions and  the answers to them :-)

Answer (score 1):

### Direct solution to the original problem

You can find all old point releases of 14.04 LTS and 16.04 LTS via these links.

http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/trusty/

http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/xenial/

For Ubuntu Server 14.04.1 via torrent,

http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/trusty/ubuntu-14.04.1-server-amd64.iso.torrent

http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/trusty/ubuntu-14.04.1-server-i386.iso.torrent

and the iso files directly (if it does not work with torrents),

http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/trusty/ubuntu-14.04.1-server-amd64.iso

http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/trusty/ubuntu-14.04.1-server-i386.iso

You find the corresponding md5sums at

http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/trusty/MD5SUMS

### Comment to upgrading from the second point release (14.04.2 LTS)

Only the first and fifth point release have LTS. See this link (and scroll down),

http://www.ubuntu.com/info/release-end-of-life

You can keep upgrading from the second point release by upgrading the [LTS enablement stack](https://askubuntu.com/questions/248914/what-is-hardware-enablement-hwe), but it is risky (known to cause problems with hardware drivers, "If it ain't broke, don't fix it"). Therefore I would say that it is best to stay with the first point release until the fifth point release is available (14.04.1 LTS and 16.04.1 LTS ...) particularly for servers.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I have finally figure it out.

14.04.2 will be updated to 14.04.5 in august 2016 with a standard "dist-upgrade". So my server with the version 14.04.2 is supported until 2019.

Thanks!

Comment: No, you didn't get it.

Comment: Help me understand it.