# Why kernel version doesn't match Ubuntu version in a Docker container?

Tags: kernel, docker, container

I have a Docker container built from Ubuntu 14.10. When I log in to the container to check the Ubuntu version and kernel version I see the following:

```
root@~$>> lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.10
Release:    14.10
Codename:   utopic   

root@~$>> uname -a
    Linux ambiata-aws 3.13.0-24-generic #47-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 2 23:30:00 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I thought that Ubuntu 14.10 was supposed to be kernel version 3.16 (as stated [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UtopicUnicorn/ReleaseNotes)), so why do I have kernel version 3.13.0-24-generic ?

The reason I am asking is because there is a patch in 3.13.0-29-generic that I would like to have (that is, having fallocate working on AUFS in my docker container) which is discussed [here](https://www.mail-archive.com/aufs-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg04660.html).

Comment: Is the container running on Ubuntu Trusty? If so, that would be why.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From [What is Docker?](https://www.docker.com/what-docker):

> LIGHTWEIGHT
>
> Containers running on a single machine share the same operating system
>   kernel; they start instantly and use less RAM. Images are constructed
>   from layered filesystems and share common files, making disk usage and
>   image downloads much more efficient.

Containers run on the host OS kernel. In your case, the host could be a Ubuntu 14.04 (running the original kernel) or a Ubuntu 12.04 (running kernel from trusty's [hardware enablement](https://askubuntu.com/q/248914/65926) stack).

If the host is Ubuntu 14.04 you could install kernel 3.16:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-utopic
```

Or kernel 3.19:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-vivid
```

For Ubuntu 12.04, kernel 3.13 is latest official one.

Comment: Do you mean I would have to upgrade the host kernel? There's no way to just upgrade the container's kernel?

Comment: @jcm There's no kernel inside a container. Even if you install a kernel, it won't be loaded when the container starts. The very purpose of a container is to isolate processes without the need to run a new kernel. That is also why containers are restricted to Linux. If you need to run another OS or another kernel version you have to make use of virtualization.