# Did Canonical just downgrade the kernel?

Tags: 14.04, kernel, updates, android, mtp

I'm on 14.04 LTE and I just got a regular update. I ran "uname -r" and it seems the kernel is now "3.13.0-65-generic."

I'm very happy with this, because MTP now works with my Android phone (It [didn't before the update](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gvfs/+bug/1314556).)

Was the kernel version for 14.04 LTE different before this update? What kernel version used to be in 14.04 LTE?

Edit: The MTP issue must have been caused by something else. Meh, forget this post, lol. I played with an old Clonezilla image of my system, and MTP even worked with that now. Maybe something with my Android phone.

Comment: Why do you ask if the kernel was downgraded? You don't know what the previous version was.

Comment: Where in particular are they saying 3.17 is the kernel for 14.04?

Comment: In this thread they are talking about the kernel being 3.17 for 14.04 LTE. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gvfs/+bug/1314556 Knowing what kernel version caused the problem is interesting if one wants to try other distros that are based on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can track the current kernel version by looking at the version of [`linux-generic`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/linux-generic):

```
$ apt-cache policy linux-generic
linux-generic:
  Installed: 3.13.0.65.71
  Candidate: 3.13.0.65.71
```

The history of versions can be seen from [the changelog for this package](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/l/linux-meta/linux-meta_3.13.0.65.71/changelog):

```
linux-meta (3.13.0.65.71) trusty; urgency=medium

  * linux ABI 3.13.0-65

 -- Brad Figg <brad.figg@canonical.com>  Mon, 21 Sep 2015 11:46:15 -0700

linux-meta (3.13.0.64.72) trusty; urgency=medium

  * linux ABI 3.13.0-64

 -- Luis Henriques <luis.henriques@canonical.com>  Wed, 09 Sep 2015 13:11:37 +0100

linux-meta (3.13.0.63.71) trusty; urgency=low

  * Fix up dandling linux-*-hwe-* meta packages.  When we do not have a
    flavour default it back to the generic packages.  (LP: 1489487).

 -- Brad Figg <brad.figg@canonical.com>  Fri, 28 Aug 2015 09:12:14 -0700

linux-meta (3.13.0.63.70) trusty; urgency=medium

  [ Brad Figg ]

  * ABI bump

 -- Brad Figg <brad.figg@canonical.com>  Fri, 14 Aug 2015 13:33:03 -0700
```

It doesn't look like the kernel has been *downgraded* recently.

Comment: In this thread they are talking about the kernel being 3.17 for 14.04 LTE. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gvfs/+bug/1314556 What are they talking about?

Comment: @Fiksdal again: where in particular? I am not interested in reading an entire bug report.

Comment: For example, Anton wrote: " Ok, I have found a workaround solution, at least for my case - just downgrade the kernel to 3.16 (default version on 14.04 is 3.19)." With Ctrl-F you can also find many other examples.

Comment: @Fiksdal yeah, he's not using the default kernel. He's using the updated kernel from the 15.04 HWE. See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack, http://askubuntu.com/questions/248914/what-is-hardware-enablement-hwe

Comment: OK. I don't understand this fully, but thanks for the input.

Comment: I made some effort to understand this better. I have accepted and upvoted your answer.