# no sound in ubuntu 14.04, on board sound card not working (?)

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, sound, alsa

I have bought a new dual boot system with windows 7 and ubuntu 14.04. When I boot into windows everything works fine, when I boot to ubuntu there is no sound. I have red and followed the instructions in:

http://www.unixmen.com/2012003-howto-resolve-nosound-problem-on-ubuntu/

but the problem is not solved. I also have a laptop with the exact same configuration where everything works fine thus I compared the two and found some differences between them. The differences are

1. In the sound settings there is no "play sound through" item, while in my laptop under "play sound through" there is "speakers - internal sound". Don't need to say that the speakers are correctly plugged into the computer since when I boot into win7 everything works great.
2. When alsamixer is loaded the "item" in the pc says PDIF whereas the item in the laptop says "master"
3. Alsamixer needs a different terminal command to load. In the laptop I just use **alsamixer**, in the pc I have to use **alsamixer -c 1** because alsamixer results in "no such file or directory".

It looks like the on board sound card (my motherboard is ASUS MOTHERBOARD H110M-K D3 ) is not working in ubuntu. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Very likely it is not yet supported. You can try a to boot a live version of Ubuntu 16.04 (currently daily build) and see if it works.

Also, since 14.04 is a LTS version, you may have luck using the hardware enablement kernel. See here for details:  [What is hardware enablement (HWE)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/248914/what-is-hardware-enablement-hwe)

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that enabling the HWE by following the directions here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack got sound working for me using 14.04 on this same motherboard.