# How to stop updating of non-HWE kernels after installing HWE kernels in Ubuntu LTS releases?

Tags: apt, kernel, lts

I ran the following a week ago to upgrade from 16.04.1 to 16.04.2 with HWE:

```
sudo apt install --install-recommends xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04
```

It installed a 4.8 kernel which I'm running now. Just now, I ran the following:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

This installed the `4.4.0-62-generic` kernel and made that the kernel that will be booted into, I think, because it's pointed to by `/initrd.img` and `/vmlinuz`. How do I stop future updates of the 4.4 kernel series and set the kernel that will be booted into next time back to the 4.8 kernel series?

Comment: Very timely because @cl-netbox recommended your line 1 to me today and I mentioned there are negative impacts reported in Ask Ubuntu. You should be able to see 4.8 kernels under ***Advanced Options*** menu in grub but more importantly the highest numbered kernel should always be the default.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I encountered this this morning, fortunately I stopped it before it installed the new kernel.  The HWE instructions should have covered this IMHO.

To prevent future problems of this nature, just delete the linux-generic entries.  Until you do this, you will have two sets of packages that can be updated with different kernels.

`sudo apt remove linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic`

Future kernel updates will come through the `linux-generic-hwe-16.04` package.

Comment: I've tried this, and it stops the kernel, but it doesn't stop the following: `The following NEW packages will be installed: linux-tools-4.4.0-65 linux-tools-4.4.0-65-generic`. How do I stop those?

Comment: I don't have any linux-tools* installed, but from messing around in a virtual machine, it looks like you should remove `linux-tools-generic` and install `linux-tools-generic-hwe-16.04`. But caveat, I have no experience with this.

Comment: It looks like removing those two packages also removed `linux-tools-virtual`—so I think that's the main package—and installing `linux-tools-virtual-hwe-16.04` put in the tools packages for the 4.8 kernel version.

Comment: FWIW this answer seems to be pretty valid for 18.04 too.

Answer (score 1):

If you manually choose desired kernel, it wont reverse it back. So far 4.8 HWE was installed as dependency, as far as I understad. Try:

```
$ sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04
```

Then you may try `dist-upgrade` again.

Comment: Those commands (`install` and `dist-upgrade`) set the HWE kernel package to manually installed, but don't do anything to unset the 4.4 kernel. `/initrd.img` and `/vmlinuz` still both point to the 4.4 kernel.

Comment: `apt policy linux-generic` also still shows as installed with the 4.4 kernel's version. Should I `apt remove linux-generic`?

Comment: Have you tried to reboot? I suspect that links to right kernel is set somewhere in boot process, because most time you have more than one kernel availabl to boot, but links are not with versions.

Comment: As  removing generic kernel I would not rush with it.  And if you ask about `linux-generic` `apt policy`  tells you aboout `linux-generic` ;)

Comment: I rebooted and the 4.8 kernel is running, even though, oddly enough, `/initrd.img` and `/vmlinuz` still point to the 4.4 kernel. To make sure this stops future 4.4 downloads, I'm going to see if the next 4.4 kernel update comes in during a future `apt update && apt dist-upgrade`.

Comment: It is bit weird (linking on 4.4), but no worry here either. I don't see any practical use them on working system. They were used by LILO, but I can't recall any practical use for them now.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex you were on the right track with your comment about removing `linux-generic`.  See my answer.