# Dell XPS 13, Ubuntu 16.04, problem with Adapter DA200 i915

Tags: dell, hdmi, i915

I have a problem with the Dell Adapter DA200 with my Dell XPS 13.
The OS is Ubuntu 16.04, kernel 4.15.0.
I installed the patch for i915 usbc (https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=93578&dgc=SM&cid=60904&lid=730074515&linkId=32430080) and it worked until last week.
For the module i915-usbc, I used kernel 4.10.0, but now it doesn't work.  I  see the monitor in HDMI but there is no video.

Maybe the problem is that the adapter now doesn't work?
What is the best usbc adapter to work with Ubuntu 16.04 or 18.04 for HDMI and VGA?

Comment: I had a lot of problems with that adapter when I tested it out years ago with 16.04. Testing it out now with the current HWE kernel (`4.15.0-34`; [proper installation information](https://askubuntu.com/questions/885561/how-to-stop-16-04-2-with-hwe-kernel-from-updating-to-4-4-kernels)) with no kernel patches has networking working properly without dying after a few seconds, HDMI working right when it's connected, but not VGA (at least the `Detect Displays` button in the `Displays` options doesn't detect the external screen; didn't try rebooting with the screen attached).

Comment: Another thing you might try is `Try Ubuntu` mode with an 18.04 installer DVD/USB. `Try Ubuntu` mode won't actually install 18.04, but it'll let you try the adapter out under 18.04. If that doesn't work, you can do the same with 18.10 when it's released in a little under a month, though 18.10 only gets support until July 2019 (18.04 gets support until April 2023).

Comment: Thank you. I think the problem is the adapter because doesn't work on other pc, with Linux/Windows/Apple. I'll try to buy a different one, like this https://thomashunter.name/blog/linux-compatible-usb-c-to-hdmi-adapter/

Comment: Not sure why this question was marked off topic, but this issue I encountered recently on an XPS 13 7390 with the DA200. Screen is recognised but black. I read it may work for resolutions of 1440x900 and under for some. Basically it's a bug and there seems to be a kernel patch to fix it. Also make sure you have the latest Thunderbolt firmware and drivers and BIOS, you may need to update those from Windows. I don't have the issue with an Apple USB-c to HDMI/USB. For more info check here: https://www.dell.com/community/Linux-General/XPS-13-9360-Ubuntu-16-04-DA200-no-HDMI/m-p/5133710#M15534

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I confirm that with the new adapter (https://thomashunter.name/blog/linux-compatible-usb-c-to-hdmi-adapter/), i don't need to install anything (patch, ecc...).
After few seconds the HDMI works.

- PC: Dell XPS 13
- OS: Ubuntu 16.04
- Kernel: 4.15.0-34