# Why I have both HWE and non-HWE kernels in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, kernel

In Ubuntu 18.04 I have both HWE and non-HWE kernels installed. I only use the HWE kernel (5.0) and in the past I had removed the non-HWE kernel (4.15, both images and headers). However, after some updates I noticed that 4.15 got installed again. Note that after each kernel update I also use `apt autoremove` to remove the older kernel.

**Why is the non-HWE kernel installed again? Can I completely uninstall it? How?**

Below are the linux images installed on my pc:

```
$ dpkg --list | grep linux-image
rc  linux-image-4.15.0-48-generic              4.15.0-48.51                                 amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-4.15.0-50-generic              4.15.0-50.54                                 amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-4.15.0-51-generic              4.15.0-51.55                                 amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-4.15.0-52-generic              4.15.0-52.56                                 amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-4.15.0-55-generic              4.15.0-55.60                                 amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-4.15.0-58-generic              4.15.0-58.64                                 amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-4.18.0-15-generic              4.18.0-15.16~18.04.1                         amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-4.18.0-18-generic              4.18.0-18.19~18.04.1                         amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-4.18.0-20-generic              4.18.0-20.21~18.04.1                         amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-4.18.0-21-generic              4.18.0-21.22~18.04.1                         amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-4.18.0-22-generic              4.18.0-22.23~18.04.1                         amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-4.18.0-24-generic              4.18.0-24.25~18.04.1                         amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-4.18.0-25-generic              4.18.0-25.26~18.04.1                         amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-5.0.0-23-generic               5.0.0-23.24~18.04.1                          amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-5.0.0-25-generic               5.0.0-25.26~18.04.1                          amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-generic                        4.15.0.58.60                                 amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
ii  linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04              5.0.0.25.82                                  amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
```

And the headers:

```
$ dpkg --list | grep linux-headers
ii  linux-headers-4.15.0-58                    4.15.0-58.64                                 all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 4.15.0
ii  linux-headers-4.15.0-58-generic            4.15.0-58.64                                 amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 4.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-5.0.0-23                     5.0.0-23.24~18.04.1                          all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 5.0.0
ii  linux-headers-5.0.0-23-generic             5.0.0-23.24~18.04.1                          amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 5.0.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-5.0.0-25                     5.0.0-25.26~18.04.1                          all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 5.0.0
ii  linux-headers-5.0.0-25-generic             5.0.0-25.26~18.04.1                          amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 5.0.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-generic                      4.15.0.58.60                                 amd64        Generic Linux kernel headers
ii  linux-headers-generic-hwe-18.04            5.0.0.25.82                                  amd64        Generic Linux kernel headers
```

Comment: Did you remove the metapackage `linux-generic`?

Comment: No, just the kernels. So that's why they got reinstalled. Thank you for this. Is there anything else that I should remove?

Comment: I answered a question like this some time ago, but I;m on a primitive device right now and can;t search well. See if you can find this question on the site, if not, in a few hours I will try. This question should be closed as a duplucate of that one so I need to try and find it.

Comment: Here it is (I got curious): https://askubuntu.com/a/885582/243321  Be sure to read the comments, they cover some stuff I didn't have installed.  Maybe it's not a duplicate because it's for 16.04

Comment: Thanks. It's exactly the same thing. I don't think that there is any difference between 16.04 and 18.04 apart from the different numbers. You can vote to close it as duplicate.