# How do I revert from 4.15.0-72 generic back to 4.15.0.70 generic?

Tags: shutdown

Running Ubuntu 18.04.3 ---------------------
I think the 4.15.0-72 generic kernel is corrupt or perhaps just incapable of working properly on my older laptop - it will freeze on shutdown every time when using the default 4.15.0-72 generic, but will shutdown fine when I interrupt boot-up and select 4.15.0-70 generic to boot instead... or is there something else going on?

Comment: Do you just want to set the older kernel as the default to boot into?

Comment: Do you just want to set the older kernel as the default to boot into? YES!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

backup old version

```
sudo cp /etc/default/grub /etc/default/grub.backup
```

edit grub config file

```
 sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Change

```
#GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_DEFAULT="Advanced options for Ubuntu>Ubuntu, with Linux 4.15.0-70-generic"
```

save, then

```
sudo update-grub
sudo reboot
```

Comment: are you saying change the line with GRUB_DEFAULT=0 to #GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_DEFAULT="Advanced options for Ubuntu>Ubuntu, with Linux 4.15.0-70-generic"?

Comment: Comment out the old line so you know what it used to say by prefacing it with a #.
Then add the new line below it.

Comment: Awesome! That fixed the hanging shutdown... wonder what's wrong with the newer kernel? How'd it get corrupted? Could the next kernel version 'fix' the corruption? (I'm rambling!)

Comment: I am glad it helped. I read it caused problems with some touchpads too. I use the HWE kernel so I have no experience with it myself.

Comment: Noticed it kinda quit doing 'updates' (says computer is up to date week after week...) - is this due to my use of the older kernel which would have no 'new updates' since it's 'obsolete' with the release of the newer kernel that was giving me problems? And, will the next release to the next kernel version be 'allowed' after this grub edit and thus resume updates?

Comment: There was a big gap in 18.04 updates over the US holidays. I started getting updates again this week.  Manually selecting a kernel should have no impact on updates, but if new kernels get installed, the system won't use them unless you remove the forced selection in grub. I think a lot of new (non-HWE) kernels came out this week, but most of my systems are HWE and weren't affected.

Comment: So, I should probably un-edit my grub in say a month or so (ie restore the original default setting) and see if if thing updates to the next newer kernel version, and then starts doing updates again, but also does not re-create the shutdown problem...

Comment: Now that you know how to select an old kernel if you need to, that seems like a good plan.

Comment: what's this kernel version 5.0 (as opposed to staying with 4.15.0...) all about - recommend?

Comment: That's the HWE kernel, which I use  on most of my systems. You can read about it here, and how to upgrade to it.  Eventually you'll have to, or stop getting kernel updates. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack If you go that route, look at this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/885582/243321