# Ubuntu 18.04. not shutting down

Tags: 18.04, shutdown, freeze

Ubuntu 18.04 freezes during shutdown. I tried all options, but nothing worked.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I revert from 4.15.0-72 generic back to 4.15.0.70 generic?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1196201/how-do-i-revert-from-4-15-0-72-generic-back-to-4-15-0-70-generic)

Comment: I am using the 5.0* kernel. Does this also has same issue?

Comment: Reboot with previous kernel and check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with my system. It was caused by my external hhd that went into a sleep/hibernate mode and wouldn't wake up. During the shutdown it would just keep the system hanging. Try to disconnect any external devices (including usb) and leave only the mouse + keyboard. If that doesn't work try to turn on the system and shut down right away after you login. Don't launch any programs other than the standard stuff you have loading after boot. If it shutdown without a problem than maybe you have a problem with some software otherwise we'll have to troubleshoot more. You can try using the terminal shutdown commands see if that works `sudo shutdown -P now`. Let me know how it goes and also add some details like did you close all the programs before you shutdown, did you have any errors with software before shutdown, or what do you suspect might be the problem.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Tried your steps but same problem encountered.

Comment: how old is the system? it could have a hardware failure if it's really old. Is reinstalling ubuntu an option for you?

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading one of my PC's with SSD from 18.04 (kernel 4.15.0-xy) to 18.04.3 (kernel 5.0.0-xy) I had the similar shutdown problem with 18.04.3. Since this problem is not happening in my other PC's with the ''original'' Ubuntu 18.04. (now kernel 4.15.0-72), I made fresh installation of the ''original'' 18.04.0 (instead of 18.04.3) and as a result there is no more shutdown problem in this PC.

Source for Ubuntu 18.04.0 (''original'') is http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/18.04.0/