# Disable HWE kernel support on Ubuntu Focal 20.04

Tags: apt, kernel, downgrade

I don't know how or why, but i have HWE installed. At least, `apt` claims there is an update for it:

```
# apt list --upgradable -a
Listing... Done
linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04/focal-updates,focal-security 5.13.0.28.31~20.04.15 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.11.0.46.51~20.04.23]
linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04/now 5.11.0.46.51~20.04.23 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 5.13.0.28.31~20.04.15]
linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04/focal 5.4.0.26.32 amd64
```

But used kernel right now seem to be a shipped version:

```
# uname -ar
Linux host1 5.4.0-91-generic #102-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 5 16:31:28 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I've tried to remove the HWE package, but it seem to install the 18.04 version...on a 20.04? As this doesn't seem right, I've stopped the process:

```
# apt remove linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-5.11.0-46-generic linux-hwe-5.11-headers-5.11.0-46
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-generic-hwe-18.04
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-generic-hwe-18.04
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,880 B of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
Abort.
```

What is wrong here? I want to stick with the 5.4.0-xx version only, and not use any HWE version on this system.

Answer (score 1):

1 - Install `linux-generic`

```
linux-generic:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 5.4.0.99.103
  Version table:
     5.4.0.99.103 500
        500 [redacted]/mirror/us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 [redacted]/mirror/us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages
     5.4.0.26.32 500
        500 [redacted]/mirror/us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
```

2 - restart, engage the GRUB menu, and boot into the linux-generic kernel

3 - remove all other `linux-generic-*, linux-headers-*`,etc

Basically you wish to achieve the opposite of the person who asked this question: [How to stop 16.04.2 with HWE kernel from updating to 4.4 kernels](https://askubuntu.com/questions/885561/how-to-stop-16-04-2-with-hwe-kernel-from-updating-to-4-4-kernels/885582#885582)

Comment: Is there anyway to do this without engaging GRUB; i.e. on a remote server?

Comment: @killachaos yes, you can edit the grub configuration and set it to boot into the hwe kernel, then reboot. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198003/set-default-kernel-in-grub