# linux-generic version does not match with uname -r

Tags: upgrade, updates, 22.04, unattended-upgrades, linux-headers

I have a question with linux-generic.

I installed linux-generic, but it did not match with kernel which was installed on my pc.

When I checked linux-generic version using dpkg -l, it showed 5.15.0.92.89. But, installed (uname -r) is 6.5.0-15-generic.

```
ii  linux-generic                              5.15.0.92.89                                amd64        Complete Generic Linux kernel and headers
ii  linux-headers-5.15.0-72                    5.15.0-72.79                                all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 5.15.0
ii  linux-headers-5.15.0-72-generic            5.15.0-72.79                                amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 5.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-5.15.0-92                    5.15.0-92.102                               all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 5.15.0
ii  linux-headers-5.15.0-92-generic            5.15.0-92.102                               amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 5.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
```

I want to keep linux-generic to match with uname -r. Actually my machine was manually upgraded from ubuntu 20.04 to ubuntu 22.04.

Are there more steps to update linux-generic version?

Comment: You can have both the GA & HWE kernel stacks installed; ie. for 22.04 LTS that will mean you have 6.5 as the HWE stack, and 5.15 or the GA stack installed, with you selecting at grub/boot which you'll use for that session. If both packages are installed, they'll continue being updated (*and if you release-upgrade to 24.04 in the future; both GA + HWE will remain installed there too*)

Comment: If you want to get rid of the GA kernel see here: https://askubuntu.com/a/885582/243321

Comment: The `linux-generic` package for the HWE (6.5.0-15-generic) Kernel is `linux-generic-hwe-22.04`.  So, if you are missing that one you can install it `sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-22.04` and that one will give you version `6.5.0.15.15`

Answer (score 1):

In video games, there's a concept of *player confusion*: A person is mistakenly tracking Player 1 while actually controlling Player 2.

You are likely watching one kernel metapackage (`linux-generic`) while actually using a different metapackage (`linux-generic-hwe-22.04`)

In Ubuntu 22.04, as of today (it changes over time):

```
linux-generic           | 5.15.0.92.89           | jammy-updates
linux-image-generic     | 5.15.0.92.89           | jammy-updates  (GA kernel)
linux-generic-hwe-22.04 | 6.5.0.15.15~22.04.8    | jammy-updates  (HWE kernel)
```

One answer is to start watching the metapackage that you are actually using.

Another answer is to change kernels (and metapackages) if you are not using the one you really want.