# Is it safe to autoremove thermald?

Tags: apt, package-management, kernel, dpkg

I have installed and uninstalled a couple of kernels(including some low latency ones) to test them out.

Now I have:

```
$ uname -r
4.8.0-39-generic
```

But now I get the following message whenever I try to install other packages:

`The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
thermald
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.`

I have tried to check the date when this thermald was installed using [this answer here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/12579/205397)

And the date it shows me is: `thermald  2016-07-19 15:48:01.000000000 -0500`

I have installed Ubuntu in Nov 2016. So this is not the date when thermald is installed.
So is it safe to remove it using `autoremove`?

```
$ lsb_release -a 
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

I have used [this tool](https://github.com/mtompkins/linux-kernel-utilities) to remove all the inactive kernels. ( Also tried 4.9.12 and 4.10 using this same tool)

I got the 4.8 kernel by doing this:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ apt-cache search linux-image
$ sudo apt-get install linux-headers-4.8.0-39-generic linux-image-4.8.0-39-generic linux-image-extra-4.8.0-39-generic
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`thermald` is not a vital package, but *recommended* by the `linux-image-generic` kernel meta-package.

You can get this information by running

```
apt show thermald
```

(shows general info about the package, note the output line "`Priority: optional`"), and

```
apt rdepends thermald
```

(shows a list of packages that directly depend on/recommend/suggest `thermald`).

*Recommended* packages are no necessary dependencies, but normally automatically installed like those, because although the recommending package can work without them, they add important functionality.

---

So you *could* remove `thermald` if you desire to do so, but I would recommend you to fix the dependency chain and properly install the meta-package which recommends `thermald` again.

Probably this can be done in your case by running

```
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-generic
```

This should not install any real packages, providing you still have them all, just meta-packages like `linux-image-generic` or so. After that, `thermald` should no longer be in the autoremove candidate list.

---

**Edit:**

As you say you are on 16.04 LTS and want the 4.8 HWE kernel instead of the 4.4. GA kernel, make sure you have the meta-package `linux-generic-hwe-16.04` (and `xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04`) installed instead of the `linux-generic` I recommended above.

Comment: Thanks that worked. But it has installed the following packages: `linux-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-64 linux-headers-4.4.0-64-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-4.4.0-64-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-64-generic linux-image-generic`. In 16.04.2, the main LTS kernel is 4.8 right? So why is it installing 4.4 to me? I actually had to manually install 4.8.

Comment: No, the standard kernel of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (Xenial) is 4.4. You only get 4.8 in Ubuntu 16.10 (Yakkety) or by installing it manually. If you were running 16.04, it is correct behaviour that it installs the latest 4.4 kernel. It would have been helpful if your question contained information about the Ubuntu release you use and about what kernel package you installed and from where.

Comment: According to this page here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Support , the 16.04.2 has 4.8. I got 4.8 by running `apt-cache search linux-image` and `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-4.8.0-39-generic linux-image-4.8.0-39-generic linux-image-extra-4.8.0-39-generic`. The output of `lsb_release -a` gives me  `Description: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS` The meta packages were probably removed because I have used this tool to remove it: https://github.com/mtompkins/linux-kernel-utilities

Comment: Yes, 16.04's GA (general availability) kernel is 4.4, but its current HWE (hardware enablement) kernel comes from 16.10 and is version 4.8. If you originally installed an Ubuntu version below 16.04.2, it will default to the GA kernel. If you want the HWE kernels and Xorg stack instead, install `sudo apt install linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04` and remove `sudo apt purge linux-generic `. After that, `sudo apt autoremove` should clean up the rest. For more info see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack and http://askubuntu.com/questions/248914/

Comment: By doing that can I get Xorg 1.19? Because I read the fix for screen tearing is in xorg 1.19.

Comment: No, `xserver-xorg-core-hwe-16.04` is just an updated version of 1.18 as well. But I am not sure how well an HWE kernel and the GA Xorg stack work together... Should be okay, but the Ubuntu Wiki recommends upgrading both at once.

Answer (score 1):

thermald produced A LOT of problems for me on notebook. Ubuntu had random and extremely annoying lags until I removed it.

I removed thermald and everything is working just great.