# Evolution crashes when looking at contacts - Hardware Enablement Stacks (HWE) issue?

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, crash, evolution, hardware-enablement-stack

For a few weeks **Evolution** has always **crashed**.
When I switch to **Contacts** and **double-click** on a contact, Evolution crashes and often the **whole Ubuntu session** (I have to login into Ubuntu again). Sometimes Evolution crashes even when I only click once on a contact to get the **overview** of the contact. I get this **error** in the terminal:

```
$ evolution

(evolution:29482): camel-WARNING **: Failed to initialize NSS SQL
database in sql:/etc/pki/nssdb: NSS error -8126

(evolution:29482): Gdk-ERROR **: The program 'evolution' received an X
Window System error.
This probably reflects a bug in the program.
The error was 'GLXBadDrawable'.
  (Details: serial 9985 error_code 171 request_code 155 (GLX)
minor_code 29)
  (Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously;
   that is, you will receive the error a while after causing it.
   To debug your program, run it with the GDK_SYNCHRONIZE environment
   variable to change this behavior. You can then get a meaningful
   backtrace from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error()
function.)
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

When I open the same contact with the right-click menu option "Add to Contacts ...", clicking on an email address in an email and then click Edit, there is no crash and I can safely edit the contact. I can also create a new contact, but when I try to edit it from the Contacts, Evolution crashes.

Not long before I noticed the recurrent crashes I followed [instructions to opt-in for HWE (Hardware Enablement Stacks)](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/08/ubuntu-16-04-3-lts-released):

```
sudo apt install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04
```

I did not know much about much about [HWE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/248914/what-is-hardware-enablement-hwe) and wanted to have the most up-to-date system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I could **not** find a **solution** on [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evolution/+bugs) and through the [Evolution mailing list](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/evolution-list/), I tried to **uninstall** the **HWE** and it **worked**! **No crashes** anymore. Here are the **instructions** for **uninstalling** the **HWE** (Hardware Enablement Stacks):
  1. Uninstall new X stack:

```
sudo apt remove xserver-xorg-core-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-input-all-hwe-16.04 linux-generic-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-video-all-hwe-16.04
```

You’ll see the command also removes the ubuntu-desktop package. Don’t worry. The following commands will install it back.
2. Then **install** **back** the **original xserver-xorg** via commands:

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-core

sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop xserver-xorg xserver-xorg-video-all xserver-xorg-input-all libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
```

**Source**: [ubuntuhandbook.org](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/02/install-remove-enablement-stacks-ubuntu-16-04/)