# How to switch from libinput to synaptics in Ubuntu 20.04LTS?

Tags: xorg, touchpad, synaptics

Is it still possible to use synaptics for touchpad driver with Ubuntu 20.04LTS?  I have installed server-xorg-input-synaptics, renamed files so that synaptics has priority over libinput

```
/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d$ ls
10-amdgpu.conf  10-radeon.conf     31-synaptics-quirks.conf  40-libinput.conf~
10-quirks.conf  30-synaptics.conf  40-libinput.conf          70-wacom.conf
```

restarted but I still have the error

```
$ synclient
Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?
```

Answer (score 1):

The situation hasn't changed since [from libinput to synaptics in 18-04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031940/how-to-switch-from-libinput-to-synaptics-in-ubuntu-18-04): some users have problems, some have none.  I don't know why.

I installed and for some reason it did not work so I renamed the files in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d` as shown above but this did not work either.

Anyway, after removing, installing again, restarting, synaptics drives the touchpad and the standard configuration is already good.