# Touchpad on double tap moves the pointer anywhere on the screen (mainly to the top and bottom) in Ubuntu 18.04 bionic

Tags: 18.04, touchpad, scrolling

When I double tap on touchpad for two fingers scrolling, the pointer moves anywhere on the screen (mainly on the top or bottom of the screen) which is pain for me.
I am currently using Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic.

Comment: When I first installed Ubuntu on my Macbook pro I had a bad time with the touchpad.  A solution is to install Synaptic drivers. Google this and you will find.

Comment: As far as I understand, default touchpad driver is more recent but not as good as Synaptic driver.

Comment: I am now with 20.10 and the touchpad works perfectly.  It is not Synaptic but Synaptics.

Comment: https://sangams.com.np/fix-ubuntu-18-4-touchpad-not-working-properly/

Comment: I have already installed synaptics driver using "sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-hwe-18.04". But still I am facing the same problem. @PierreALBARÈDE

Comment: But my command is somewhat different than What it should be:
expected -> "sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics"
mine -> "sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-hwe-18.04"
@PierreALBARÈDE

Comment: See also https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031940/how-to-switch-from-libinput-to-synaptics-in-ubuntu-18-04