# System can not reboot after completing installation

Tags: boot, system-installation

Recently, I made a bootable USB stick with version 18.04 and 
install OS from the USB stick to the hard disk.
The installation process follows the normal steps without any special configuration.

The whole installation process is correct and completed.
Then it shows a button to request doing the system reboot. 
The steps of the reboot as follows:

1. Push the button, the system is trying to reboot.
2. The message show "Please remove the installation medium, then reboot".
3. Remove USB stick physically.
4. Type ENTER key and wait for a while.
   However, there is no response and message stops requesting for removing medium.

How about "then reboot"? Does it mean to press the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key and wait for the reboot by itself, or push system reset button (send reset signal) physically?

Comment: Have you tried to do what it says ? Remove the USB you installed from ?

Comment: Close voters, while this is a very basic question it's not remotely unclear. Posting answer.

Comment: Thanks for response. I have tried to remove USB stick physically after showing message. Then I type ENTER key and wait for a while, but there is no response.

Comment: I face the same question, and my solution is ... unplug my USB and wait ..., and after probably 30min the computer reboot itself.

Answer (score 34):

I have the same problem. I put Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS on USB stick as a bootable volume. Specifically, I formatted it on Mac and then ran it on a pc.

The solution I found was to *press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> - <kbd>C</kbd> after ejecting the USB stick*.

Comment: This solved the problem for me too

Comment: This solves the problem, although it shows a brief error message.

Comment: Thanks man, saved my day.

Comment: Same problem with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS desktop

Comment: Haha thanks. Worked. You saved me 

Answer (score 3):

It's been my experience that if you do what the system requests of you you will get far more positive results than if you don't. `Please remove the installation medium` means that if you have installed **from** a USB flash drive, unplug it and if you've install **from** an optical disk, eject it prior to pressing enter to reboot the system. This is the expected behavior. If this doesn't seem to apply to you **add further detail to your question** specifying what media you are installing from **and** to.

Comment: Thanks for response. I tried to remove USB stick physically 
after showing the message about remove installation medium. 
Then typing ENTER KEY and wait for while. But there is no response.
It is about that I try to do installation from USB stick to Hard Disk.
on INTEL Coffee Lake platform.

Comment: @johnchn Be aware that booting from a USB flash drive can possibly change your expected drive designations. Prior to installing, after booting from the installation media, open a terminal and check the output of `sudo parted -l
` to make sure you are installing to the device desired. Coffee Lake is a bit too expensive for me, but you might try installing a [HWE kernel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/248914/what-is-hardware-enablement-hwe) prior to installation to see if you get different results.

Comment: Thanks. Currently, I install OS image with version 18.04 from USB stick to hard disk. Although system can not reboot after installation, I can boot from hard disk after removing USB stick and power off . It means installation is correct and success. System booting from hard disk is functional.

Comment: @johnchn Always glad to help. The way we say thanks here is by accepting (clicking the check mark next to ) and upvoting (clicking the up arrow next to) the most helpful answer to our questions. This helps others with the same problem to find answers that work. Once you've reached the necessary reputation here you will gain further [privileges.](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges) Welcome to AskUbuntu!

Answer (score 2):

A poweroff following by a cold start works the same as a reboot after the Ubuntu installation has been finished and you get the `Please remove the installation medium, then reboot.` message. Just make sure that the installation medium is removed before starting the computer again or it will boot from the Ubuntu installation medium again instead of booting normally from what is installed on the hard drive.

1. Shut down the computer by holding down the power button.
2. Remove the installation medium (USB or DVD). A DVD can be removed by manually ejecting the CD/DVD tray if you temporarily stop the boot process by entering the BIOS/UEFI setup utility, eject the CD/DVD tray, remove the DVD, close the CD/DVD tray, and then exit the BIOS/UEFI setup utility without saving any changes.
3. Wait for one minute and then cold start the computer by pushing the power button.
4. Now your new Ubuntu installation will be able to boot normally.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Lunix on VM virtual box. Similar situation was faced in my case as well. Kindly note that i was installing Linux through its image(iso) file. 
Please carry out following steps if you face same error:

1. go to settings from VirtualBox manager
2. locate storage option and controller:IDE,then remove .iso file from there
3. uncheck live CD/DVD
4. close current running ubuntu machine
5. restart it after above steps.
6. you will be on login page of your linux OS

I hope this would help you out.

Comment: I couldn't find how to do the step 3 but the rest worked. Thx