# Ubuntu stuck rebooting and installing

Tags: system-installation, reboot

I am installing Ubuntu 18.04 off of a USB stick. It allows me to get the whole way through the installation process until the end.
Most others are prompting to remove installation medium, then click enter after which, the system reboots and opens Ubuntu.
For me however, after the installation is complete, I am not given this prompt. The screen goes completely black and the message comes up which says `Please remove the installation medium, then reboot`.

I am unsure of how to reboot from this prompt as there are no options. It allows me to type and enter like a command prompt, but there's no feedback, so I don't know if any commands are working or not.
After a few minutes, the computer shuts down itself, and when I turn it back on, I am greeted with a `No Bootable Device` screen.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [System can not reboot after completing installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1043763/system-can-not-reboot-after-completing-installation)

Answer (score 0):

You can try pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd> at the same time... That helped me to shut down and reboot again... I hope that helps you too.