# How to update to a specific version of Ubuntu (NOT latest version)

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, upgrade, versions

How can i update to a specific version of ubuntu ?
F.e. 16.04.0 to 16.04.3 instead of 16.04.6 (latest 16.04 release at this time).
Is there a solution that works on 16.04 and 18.04 (18.04.0 to 18.04.1 INSTEAD to 18.04.2)?

Yes, ive seen similar questions, but none of them were answered with a way to update to a version that is NOT the latest version.

this is intended for a test environment, to test software during the different update versions of ubuntu.
Start with one software install state and update it to X, where it is tested.

Comment: An interesting question, in that AFAIK the final digit does not imply a version of Ubuntu, but the 3rd or 6th update of the installation ISO

Comment: This sounds a tiny bit like a [X-Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Also, have a look here https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

Answer (score 0):

You probably already have the hardware stacks:  it is basically picking the corresponding kernel when GRUB pops up. So the closest to what you want is by picking the 16/18.10 kernel and have the hardware support from 16/18.10. Mind that this only works for the hardware; the software will still be the same versions.

Some extra info:

```
16.04.1 = 16.04 + Hardware stack for 16.10
16.04.2 = 16.04 + Hardware stack for 17.04
...
18.04.1 = 18.04 + Hardware stack for  18.10
etc
```

and

```
sudo apt install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04
```

will install the 18.04 hardware stack but there is no separate 18.10, 19.04 stacks as soon as the new release arrives. This will always upgrade as far as it can go so there is no method to do exactly what you want. You can check with

```
hwe-support-status --verbose
```

(only works on LTS versions).

Related:

[What is hardware enablement (HWE)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/248914/what-is-hardware-enablement-hwe)

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

Comment: No copy/paste error ;-) 2nd: yes; issue OP has could be done by selecting the specific kernel.