# Mi pc no encuentra redes

Tags: 18.04, wireless

Instale Ubuntu 18.04 en mi PC, luego de haber tenido Windows10, **instale un nuevo kernel** pero sigue sin buscar redes, solo funciona mediante una red cableada

La salida del comando  lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3 es la siguiente **Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:d723]   Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:8319]**

y la salida de el comando uname -r es la siguiente : **4.15.0-91-generic**

gracias, espero respuestas

## Google translate:

Install Ubuntu 18.04 on my PC, after having Windows 10, install a new kernel but still not looking for (WiFi?) networks, it only works through a wired network

The output of the `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` is the following:

```
Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec: d723] 
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c: 8319]
```

and the output of the `uname -r` command is as follows:

```
4.15.0-91-generic
```

thanks, I wait for answers

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` and also: `uname -r` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. This is an English language site. Please post only in English.

Comment: i need help, and my english is so bad

Comment: Do you have both Windows and Ubuntu in dual boot or have you replaced Windows 10 with Ubuntu? Is the WiFi interface missing or WiFi cannot find your home access point? Please edit and update the question.

Comment: If your PC is a recent design, you may need a more recent kernel. Either install a layer version (19.10, until 20.04 is out) or try a ["Hardware Enablement" (a.k.a. "HWE") kernel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/248914/what-is-hardware-enablement-hwe).

Comment: Notice that your device is 10ec:d723. Please follow the duplicate to install a working driver.

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que instales una versión de Ubuntu más reciente para quitar ese problema. O puedes intentar actualizar tus paquetes desde la terminal con:

```
    $ sudo apt-get upgrade
```

y después con

```
    $ sudo apt-get update
```

El primer comando actualiza los paquetes en tu repositorio, y el segundo actualiza los paquetes que tengas sin actualizar en tu computadora.

Comment: Hola, los paquetes ya los actualice varias veces, es seguro que instalando una version mas reciente se elimine ese problema?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. This is an English language site. Please post only in English.

Comment: Some versions are not compatibly, you have to search which ubuntu distro is ok for you