# How do module updates get propagated to LTS users?

Tags: kernel, wacom, release-management

I (and others) recently had an issue with the input-wacom module which has been fixed by the developers.  I tested it by manually compilng the module and the maintainers have now released the fix and apparently it has gone upstream to the "stable kernels".. my question is, will this (or when will this) new module version now propagate to the 20.04 LTS?  Details here:

https://github.com/linuxwacom/input-wacom/issues/234

Many thanks,

Simon

Comment: If you are using the [20.04 HWE kernel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/248914/what-is-hardware-enablement-hwe), then you should already be running kernel 5.8 instead of 5.4. 20.04 HWE users will get bumped again to 5.10 in July 2021. If you are not using HWE, then you must file a bug report in Launchpad (the WACOM thread was correct about that).

Comment: Thanks - I'm running 5.4.0.. so I will go and file a bug in launchpad.