# Ubuntu 20.04 - How can I enable HWE?

Tags: 20.04, upgrade, kernel, xorg, hardware-enablement-stack

I've read around that now it should be possible to have kernel 5.8 with HWE 20.04.2.
Looks like this was released last week, but my 20.04 system is still on 5.4.

I've seen [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/248914/what-is-hardware-enablement-hwe) answer and can clearly see that the kernel should be available.

What about *xorg*? Another user is suggesting the following:

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-20.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-20.04
```

Unfortunately I get the errors

```
E: Unable to locate package xserver-xorg-hwe-20.04
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'xserver-xorg-hwe-20.04'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'xserver-xorg-hwe-20.04'
```

Am I doing something wrong? Or the *xorg* packages are not anymore on HWE upgrade cycles?

Thanks!

*appendix*

```
ma@scv:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack   HWE is default for desktop now, but not for server. See the "Server - Installing the HWE stack is simple" bit, which has the command @Pilot6 has provided

Comment: @guiverc Is it possible that a kernel update could also skip over what could be considered old hardware support and actually induce a regression on some desktop machines?  The wiki in above comment seems to imply that exact point regarding 20.04 LTS but I am not certain.  It does seem to advise not updating and provides steps to regress to earlier kernel.  The terminology is a bit heavy to understand for a layman such as myself.

Comment: Sorry @xtrchessreal I'm not sure what you mean. There was a change with 20.04 that makes it different to prior LTS releases; plus server & desktop on 20.04 are no longer the same (server defaults to using the GA/general) where desktop defaults to HWE (unless oem.... yeah that is complex; it's possible desktop installs can use GA by default for oems).  Switching to 5.8 had some flaws with 20.04 GNOME/Ubuntu desktop users; no flaw with kernel, but missed... that are fixed now; those were mistakes that are now rectified (we're all human)

Comment: @xtrchessreal possibly the best link I can provide for more details is https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/improvements-for-hardware-support-in-ubuntu-desktop-installation-media/20606  (which I see anyway as result of recent Technical Board discussion...), but really I don't understand your question sorry.

Comment: @guiverc Thank you, the discourse link is a bit easier to understand and explains why a point release roll back is not possible.  I believe this also points to issues I am having could be unique to my old dell. Which, when I am frustrated enough to pursue aggressively I will research the necessary fixes or develop a new AU question specific to them.  I could also get lucky and somewhere along the way an update will solve them inexplicably.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is no `xserver-xorg-hwe-20.04`. Graphical stack is upgraded as other packages.

To get the 5.8 kernel, you need only

```
sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-20.04
```

Comment: Thanks - all good now. Btw, why didn't it get automatically installed? My other pc, with a _fresh_ 20.04.1 installation did upgrade to 5.8 automatically as part of _dist-upgrade_, whilst my main pc, an upgrade from 18.04.3, did not (had to run this command).

Comment: It is by design. You installed from a 20.04 iso.

Comment: @Pilot6 running above on Ubuntu 20.04 installed me `Linux 5.11.0-27-generic` is that expected?

Comment: @KasunSiyambalapitiya Exactly. Now it is 5.11.