# Difference between linux-image-5.11.0-16-generic & linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04?

Tags: package-management, kernel

These two packages look exactly the same. What's the difference and why install one instead of the other ?

[linux-image-5.11.0-16-generic](https://packages.ubuntu.com/hirsute/linux-image-generic)

[linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04](https://packages.ubuntu.com/hirsute/linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04)

Comment: Primarily package name... the first you list is for 21.04, with the current kernels for normal releases re-packaged for the prior LTS release systems with HWE enabled (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack & https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/RollingLTSEnablementStack)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is hardware enablement (HWE)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/248914/what-is-hardware-enablement-hwe)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primarily package names.

The first you list is for *hirsute* or 21.04 a standard/interim release.

Ubuntu kernels for standard release are re-packaged for LTS (*long-term-support*) releases where HWE is enabled.  The second is the LTS packaged version for boxes using the *hardware enablement* (HWE) stack.

The second package name you list will change over the life of the system, it was 5.8 (20.10 kernel) before the 21.04 kernel is introduced... ie. the kernel inside will change before it reaches it's final 22.04 (GA stack) kernel.

See

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack
- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/RollingLTSEnablementStack

Comment: This makes sense, with your explanation about how `linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04` will change which kernel it installs.