# Using Ubuntu on latest hardware

Tags: kernel, hardware-enablement-stack

Like many others, I have a dilemma with using Ubuntu on my newly built desktop PC. Both 20.04.4 LTS (Focal Fossa) and 21.10 (Impish Indri) installed Linux 5.13.0-19-generic x86_64. The in-built Intel WiFi on the ASRock motherboard (with 12th Gen i7 CPU, NVMe storage, no graphics card) would not work. The outcome of numerous internet searches suggested Linux 5.16 or later was required and the usual solution was to install it from the Ubuntu Mainline Kernel PPA. This worked so I am now running Linux 5.16.0-051600-generic x86_64.

However, as pointed out very clearly in the search results, I have an unsupported and unsigned kernel. So, the dilemma is which one of three ways to go forward.

A) Stay with the 5.16 kernel for a year or two until a Ubuntu release supports my hardware. This of course means running without security updates on an unsigned kernel.

B) Install the latest kernel each time a release is available. I assume latest kernel releases will include many / most security & bug fixes as well as improved support for my hardware. This benefit may be offset by a more difficult migration to a future Ubuntu release, maybe even a full re-install if my applications won't work or the system becomes unstable.

C) Accept that Ubuntu does not meet my essential requirements, before I start installing applications and using the system for real work.

I (and maybe many others with new hardware) would appreciate some guidance on how to resolve this dilemma.

Comment: Well, actually soon there won't be any new releases for 5.16. That is because it is not an LTS kernel but a "stable" one, which will be superseded by the next "stable", the 5.17. kernel.org still shows 5.16 among releases, but I presume not for long. With that said, did you try package `linux-oem`? That is a [OEM kernel](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/OEMKernel), it is an older kernel but with drivers from newer releases. It may include the driver you're interested in, you gotta test it.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I will first investigate the OEM Kernel, I need to understand how to install it and prepare for an uninstall it if doesn't work. I will then do same for the beta. I will post a comment on the outcomes.

Comment: Test 0f [tag:linux-oem] : @Hi-Angel, I did try this, but failed - the sudo apt install linux-oem-20.04b command failed to find the kernel. I searched for a reason / fix but could not find something understandable. Maybe this does not work on my installation which is 21.10 (Impish Indri). Thanks again for the suggestion.

Comment: Re Option D (Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (beta): @user68186, I tried running 22.04 from a USB stick and the on-board WiFi worked, though a slower connection. So, I performed the online update from 21.10 to 22.04 (i.e. not a full re-install from the iso). This worked well, except my system boots from the Mainline Kernel PPA 5.16 - the 5.15 kernel is left as a boot option in Grub. I'm not sure if it is worth booting the 5.15 kernel. So, I suppose I am further down my voyage of discovery with Ubuntu but still have the dilemma. Maybe I have posed an unreasonable question. Thanks again for your comments.

Comment: @NickTrial did you try just `apt install linux-oem`? Without the 20.04b postfix? I presume this should work on any release.

Comment: @user68186: I went the whole way, booted from 5.15.0-25-generic, then uninstalled the 5.16 kernel. All looks OK, so thank you.

Comment: @Hi-Angel, I didn't try [apt install linux-oem]. I am not on 22.04 Beta. I tried [apt search linux-oem] and the outcome is linux-oem-20.04/jammy 5.15.0.25.27 amd64. So I guess [linux-oem-20.04] would work. However, It looks like the generic kernel is working for me so I should leave it there. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Option D

You can try installing Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (currently in beta). It comes with the 5.15 kernel if that works in your hardware. **However, note that until 22.04 is finalized and released in April 21, 2022, questions about it is off-topic here.**

You may also update from Ubuntu 21.10 running kernel 5.16 to Ubuntu 22.04 following the instructions in the [OMG Ubuntu site](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/04/how-to-upgrade-to-ubuntu-22-04-lts). If you do this after the upgrade you will still be running the 5.16 kernel, as it is newer than the stock kernel in Ubuntu 22.04.

### If you upgrade from Ubuntu 20.10:

You can use the advanced option in `grub` to boot from kernel 5.15 that was installed when you upgraded to 22.04. If all goes well, you can uninstall the kernel 5.16, while you are booted using the latest 5.15 kernel. That way, you will be on the Ubuntu supported stock kernel.  and that will be updated by the update-upgrade system as needed.

If it works, you will have a fully supported system (that will receive all the security updates for the next 5 years) next month.

## For the Future

Other users may have the same dilemma in the near future. For them there are two paths:

1. Install Ubuntu 22.10 that will be released in October 2022. This is a short term release and will expire in 9 months.
2. Wait for Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS. This point release will probably include [Hardware Enablement](https://askubuntu.com/questions/248914/what-is-hardware-enablement-hwe) and have the same kernel version as the one the 22.10 will have.

Hope that helps