# Recover from bad distro upgrade to 22.04 LTS

Tags: 20.04, upgrade, kernel

I was running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on my laptop and decided to upgrade to 22.04. The update went well until it came the time to update the kernel. The default Ubuntu partitioning scheme creates a 705 MB partition which ran out of space when updating grub (I guess). The result was a bricked laptop. I got a working system by removing `linux-image-5.15.0.47` and falling back to `5.13.0.52`, but I don't get *any* kernel upgrades anymore.

How do I get back to the regular kernel upgrade path? I never installed any custom kernels as I mostly work remotely through SSH. I want to keep the 22.04 upgrade.

I did clean up the `/boot` partition by uninstalling older kernel images, but I still do not get any kernel upgrades.

My laptop is a Lenovo Carbon X1

```sh
$ uname -a
Linux laptop 5.13.0-52-generic #59-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 15 20:17:13 UTC x86_64  x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

If I run `sudo apt update` and then `sudo apt upgrade`, it says there aren't any upgrades. If I use `apt-cache search linux-image | grep generic` I can see `linux-image-5.15.0-48-generic` as an available package. Why can't I update?

Comment: Boot with a LiveUSB and free some space on `/boot`. It is unclear what you mean by that partition. Generally Ubuntu is installed on one partition unless lvm is used. If `/boot` has no space, the system won't boot.

Comment: And also `dist-upgrade` is not "distro upgrade" at all.

Comment: Now the question is unclear. Did you manage to boot? What do you mean by "I still do not get any kernel upgrades". What are you trying to do, how you do it and what is the result?

Comment: I have a working system that's using 5.13 instead of 5.15. I did clean up some space (sorry for not being more clear), so I can use the laptop, however, I can't upgrade to a newer kernel (and I'm having some display server hangs that I'm trying to solve by updating the kernel).

Comment: It is unclear where the `5.13` kernel came from. How did you do your "distro upgrade"? And what does `cat /etc/lsb-release` is showing?

Comment: I'm assuming that the 5.13 kernel was the latest one I had before the 18.04 -> 20.04 update.

Comment: So how did you the update?

Comment: And what is the release now? 18.04, 20.04 or 22.04?

Comment: Sorry, I was in a hurry and mixed the versions (I'm typing this on a Windows machine because I keep restarting the laptop to try and upgrade the kernel). I was running 20.04 and now I'm running 22.04, just with an older kernel.

Comment: The 5.13 kernel is *unsupported* being a kernel from Ubuntu 21.10 (20.04 LTS used it with HWE kernel stack installed, but systems upgraded to 5.15 prior to 21.10 reaching EOL so users weren't left using an unpatched/EOL kernel). Your mention of 5.13 implies you've done things to your system to force your system using the *unpatched* & *unsupported* kernel. If security matters to you, be aware of what you do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you removed the latest kernel, you removed a meta package. That's why you don't get kernel upgrades.

Run

```
sudo apt install linux-generic
```

to install non-HWE lernel,

or

```
sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-22.04
```

to install a [HWE](https://askubuntu.com/q/248914/167850) kernel.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Why the HEW kernel and not the generic one?

Comment: Oops. If you want the 5.15, it is really `linux-generic`.

Comment: Hold on. All is wrong.

Comment: I installed the `linux-generic-hwe-22.04` package and now I'm running `5.15.0-48-generic`.  What;s the HWE package for?

Comment: It is unclear what is the current release. You said you ran `dist-upgrade` on 18.04. You should have been on 18.04 after that. But you mentioned 20.04. Now you installed a package from 22.04 somehow.

Comment: `When you removed the latest kernel, you removed a meta package` ah, many thanks! That was the problem.