# Ubuntu 22.04 kernel 5.16

Tags: kernel, 22.04

Do you know if it is planned Ubuntu 22.04 to receive kernel 5.16 officially and when ?
I cannot disable secure boot so I cannot install unsigned 5.16 kernel.
Regards.

Comment: This site is manned by volunteers so no one here works for the company. So no one here likely can answer that.

Comment: Why do you need kernel 5.16? Is something not working? This might be another XY Problem https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: There are 6.0 and 5.17 in the repository. No 5.16.

Comment: 5.19 will be available as the *edge* kernel early

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kernel 5.16 won't be in 22.04.

Kernel 5.19 will be in Ubuntu 22.04.2, around January 2023.

There will no intermediate steps between 5.15 (=Ubuntu 22.04) and 5.19 (=Ubuntu 22.10). No 5.16, 5.17, nor 5.18.

To use this newer kernel when released, install the HWE metapackage: [What is hardware enablement (HWE)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/248914/what-is-hardware-enablement-hwe)

HWE upgrade occurs in January/July, approximately three months after the Interim Releases in April/October. You can easily identify the new HWE kernel by simply looking at the most recent Interim Release kernel.