# "Non-Jammy" kernels on Jammy

Tags: kernel, 22.04

I'm running Jammy LTS which came with 5.15.x kernel and I do run some tools that are dependent on kernel version. I see in jammy updates that there are also higher kernel versions available like 5.19.x or 6.2.x however these kernels are not listed as targeted for Jammy eg. on https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+publishinghistory.

I know I can install them and most likely they won't break anything but from the Canonical point of view if I'm on Jammy and I would need some support should I stay on kernels specifically released for Jammy (based on the information on launchpad) or I can use anything that is provided through jammy-updates?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is hardware enablement (HWE)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/248914/what-is-hardware-enablement-hwe)

Comment: IMO either would do. You need to decide that yourself. I would ditch any tool that requires a specific kernel and find equivalents that don't. Or code my own ;) Kernels are short lived. Our own software lasts a lot longer ;)

Comment: "*from the Canonical point of view...*" None of us here work for Canonical Ltd. We are your peers -- fellow users who volunteer to help others. That's what "Community Support" means.

Comment: @user535733 well I'm not native speaker and in my local language "the point of view of subject A" does not mean you have to be affiliated with subject A to provide some opinion on the matter, and of course nobody forces you to provide any answer, thats what I though "Community support" means ;)

Comment: @muru yeah it does to some extent, thanks. I'm sticking with listed kernels so far.