# ubuntu 22.04 os with kernel version 5.15.0-52-generic having frequent network/wifi disconnection or corrupt issue

Tags: networking, kernel

Ubuntu 22.04 os with kernel version 5.15.0-52-generic  having frequent network/wifi disconnection or corrupt issue

Network drivers will be corrupted after some days and ip will stops pinging

any help here

Comment: That's an old kernel. I would recommend upgrading to the [latest one](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy-updates/linux-image-5.15.0-78-generic) first.

Comment: Another option is to try the [HWE kernel line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/248914/what-is-hardware-enablement-hwe).

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.