# Can't adjust brightness on my Lenovo IdeaPad with OLED display

Tags: display, lenovo, brightness

I had bought Lenovo IdeaPad Pro 5 14IMH9 this week, but when I installed Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS, there is no option to adjust brightness. I feel like I tried everything with my friend - updating drivers, editing Linux value in grub, installing external application such as Light or Brightness controller, but nothing helped me.

Could you help, please?
Maybe it is because of the OLED display and there is no support yet?

Comment: Does you laptop have dedicated graphics card by AMD or Nvidia?

Comment: Try this https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/629410/55205

Comment: According to that Unix.SE link, kernel ≥ 5.12 should work. Have you tried https://askubuntu.com/a/1265302/1004020 ?

Comment: Comment from @ArchismanPanigrahi fixed it for me. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

On my Ideapad I use one of the Fn keys, there is also a drop brightness key next to it to reduce brightness.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use the Soft Brightness GNOME extension, as described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/629410).